# Compact linear operator on Hilbert space with no eigenvectors

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, solution-verification

I have this question given to me as a Homework problem. I suspect there must be a typo somewhere. Can anyone confirm this for me?

> Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space with a countable basis $\{\phi_k\}$.
>   Let $T:H\rightarrow H$ be a linear map defined via $$ T(\phi_k)=
>  \frac{1}{k} \phi_k, \forall k.$$ Show that $T$ is compact, but it has
>   **no eigenvectors**.

I can show compactness no problem. However, based on the statement, I think the $\phi_k$ are eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\frac{1}{k}$. Therefore, something is wrong with the question. Am I correct? If not, where is the flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Your reasoning is flawless, unlike this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. They were likely trying to write 
$$
T\phi_k=\tfrac1k\,\phi_{k+1}
$$
or something like that.

Comment: That would make sense. I can prove it with this correction. It's simply an inductive argument on the coefficients of the basis.

Comment: Yes indeed. $ $